# Saving the render target bitmap results in wrong size when background is set

Tags: c#, wpf, rendertargetbitmap

I am saving the rendered image  using render target bitmap, and it is saved properly in the given size, but when I set background to the grid in which image is placed, I am getting different output. Can any one explain this behavior?

```
    <Grid x:Name="grid1" Grid.Row="0" Background="Red">

        <Image x:Name="image1" Source="Images/butterfly.jpg"  >              
        </Image>

    </Grid>
```

Code behind

```
        RenderTargetBitmap result = GetImage(this.grid1);
        Stream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
        SaveAsPng(result, imageStream);

    public static RenderTargetBitmap GetImage(Grid view)
    {
        Size size = new Size(1122, 750);
        if (size.IsEmpty)
            return null;

        RenderTargetBitmap result = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        DrawingVisual drawingvisual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext context = drawingvisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            context.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(view), null, new Rect(new Point(), size));
            context.Close();
        }

        result.Render(drawingvisual);
        return result;
    }

    public static void SaveAsPng(RenderTargetBitmap src, Stream outputStream)
    {
        var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog()
        {
            Filter = "Image Files (*.bmp, *.png, *.jpg)|*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg"
        };
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {              
            var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(src));
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(saveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                encoder.Save(stream);
        }
    }
```

[Without Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCRRq.png)
[With Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1kMu.png)

Comment: I don't know for sure why it's doing that, but it works correctly if I change the parameter type of of GetImage to Visual (`GetImage(Visual view)`), and pass `this.image1` to it instead of `this.grid1`. I *suspect* the VisualBrush ignores the parts with no background.

Comment: It appears that the VisualBrush only uses the parts of `grid1` that have visuble content. When those parts are wider than the width you're giving it, in accordance with the VisualBrush's default Stretch value (`Fill`), it condenses the image it's got laterally to fit in the space you told it to use. You could set Stretch = Stretch.Uniform on the VisualBrush, but then it would add a white border above and below to maintain the required aspect ratio without squeezing anything.

Answer (score 3):

In order to retain the original element dimensions in the DrawingVisual, you should set the VisualBrush's `Stretch` to `None`. If necessary, you can also get precise control of the placement of the visual by setting the VisualBrush's `Viewport`, `Viewbox`, `AlignmentX` and `AlignmentY` properties.

Also consider passing the result size as an argument to your `GetImage` method, and use the most general type for the `view` argument:

```
public static BitmapSource GetImage(Visual view, Size size)
{
    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    var visualBrush = new VisualBrush
    {
        Visual = view,
        Stretch = Stretch.None
    };

    var drawingvisual = new DrawingVisual();

    using (var context = drawingvisual.RenderOpen())
    {
        context.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, new Rect(size));
    }

    bitmap.Render(drawingvisual);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Also make the `SaveAsPng` method more flexible by changing the argument type. The `outputStream` argument isn't used at all, so remove it.

```
public static void SaveAsPng(BitmapSource src)
```

Then call both methods like this:

```
var result = GetImage(grid1, new Size(1122, 750));
SaveAsPng(result);
```